# Collapsing Toolbar any time i want

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

Collapsing toolbar collapse and expands with respect to scroll of Recyclerview.Is there any option to force in collapse or expanding toolbar onToch event  ?   as Example >> i need something like-

```
edittext.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            toolbar.collapse();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: I think there are alot github libraries on this ... which u can change to implement ur task...

Comment: WOULD YOU PROVIDE ME A LINK PLEASE  @thestalker.

Comment: https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare... he was worked on beta version of it ... so u need to edit his code

Comment: Collapsing toolbar with RecyclerView works fine but i want to collapse that  on button click or touch in the activity. @thestalker